# Must declare the scalar variable with stored procedure meant to have user-defined table type as parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am fairly new to using user-defined table types so this may not be possible. I am trying to modify my stored procedure so that it takes a user-defined table type as a parameter. I have another stored procedure that is meant to insert the values into the this User defined table.

This is the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[getUser]
    (@userID int = NULL)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @PIDTable AS posts_id_table_type;

    INSERT INTO @PIDTable
        SELECT DISTINCT post_id 
        FROM siteTable.posts
        WHERE poster_id LIKE @userID
```

After this is executed, I will have the following stored procedure execute. The alter is there because I am having issues altering the stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getPostThread]
    @PIDTable posts_id_table_type READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT
        poster_id, post_id, post_time, post_text, 
        REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(post_text, ',', ';'), CHAR(13), '|'), CHAR(10), '|') AS post_text_amended
    FROM 
        siteTable.posts
    WHERE 
        post_id IN (@PIDTable)
    ORDER BY 
        post_id ASC, post_time
END
```

When I try to alter this stored procedure I get the error

> Must declare the scalar variable "@post_id_table"

Is this because I am not directly calling the second stored procedure from the first? I have seen other cases where people have a user-defined table type as the parameter which is why I am confused as to what is causing an error when I go to alter this the stored procedure.

Comment: `WHERE post_id in (@PIDTable)` you are treating it like a scalar. You need to `SELECT` from it. e.g. `WHERE post_id in (SELECT p.post_id FROM @PIDTable p)`

Answer (score 2):

You need to join it like a normal table

```sql
    FROM siteTable.posts p
    JOIN @PIDTable pid ON pid.post_id = p.post_id
```

Ideally the table type would have a primary key defined.

If the IDs in the TVP are not unique then use an `IN` or `EXISTS` instead.

```sql
    FROM siteTable.posts p
    WHERE p.post_id IN (SELECT pid.post_id FROM @PIDTable pid)
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you! If I am running these two queries one after the other, but one is not called by the other, is it possible to still have the value of @PIDTable from the first query be used as the param for the second query? EXEC one of them and then EXEC the other sort of thing?